# Leer un archivo de configuración python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, configuración

Copie este código de stackoverflow en ingles, tiene algo de  lo que quiero pero no por completo, quiero que me devuelva un  JSON. Por ejemplo: si encuentra un [Nombre] quiero que lo devuelva como json así: 'Nombre': {"texto":"option"}
Lo cual no hace. Archivo de configuración.

```
 [Settings]
  {
    "Name":"Filename",
    "Version":"1.5",
    "Author": "Authorname",
    "CustomInput": [],
    "MoreInput": [
         {
              "Name":"button",
               "Description":" un boton"
          },
           {
               "Name":"otro",
                "Description":"otro boton"
             }
     ]
    "Bolean": true
  }
 [Options]
{
 "Options":"option"
}
 [Script]
  {
   cd /dirname/
   ls
  }
```

Y esté es mi código, pero no funciona como deseo.

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
     for line in f:
        re_found = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', line)
        #re_found = re.findall('\{(.*?)\}', line)
        re_found = ''.join(re_found)
        ini_dict[re_found] = dict()
        try:
         if re_found:
            next_line = next(f)
            while re.findall('\[{(.*?)}\]',next_line):
              key,value = next_line.rstrip("\n").split(':')
              ini_dict[re_found][key.strip()] = value.strip()
              #self.ini_dict = re.findall('\{(.*?)\}', next_line)
              #print ini_dict      
              next_line = next(f)
        except StopIteration:
           #print("EOF!")
           pass
return ini_dict
```

Quiero que se imprima algo así:

```
{'Script': {"cd dirname","ls"}, 'OPTIONS': {"option":"option"}, 'Settings': {"name":"filename","Version":"1.5", "Author":"AuthorName","Bolean": true}}
```

Output:

```
{'': {}, 'Script': {}, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'Settings': {}}
```

Nota: este código dentro de una función de una clase. Lo que pase en script no me importa mucho, sólo quiero que lo devuelva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo qué tipo de archivo quieres leer, no es un .ini ni un .json, pero en fin, como sea, aquí va:

Si tu archivo es una clase de .ini que usa corchetes para designar secciones, dentro de las cuales hay json, el bucle exterior está bien. Ahí dice:

"Si encontré algo con la forma [Sección], le inserto una llave al diccionario global y hasta toparme con otra sección voy metiendo configuraciones a la presente sección".

Acto seguido itera sobre el contenido que lo separa de la otra sección, y lo seguirá haciendo mientras...

```
while re.findall('\[{(.*?)}\]',next_line):
```

Hmmm no, en realidad eso no me hace sentido.

Ahí dice que itere mientras la siguiente línea tenga la forma `{` + (opcionalmente texto) + `}`. Eso tendría algo de sentido si fuera un string y usáramos el modificador re.MULTILINE, pero leyendo un archivo línea a línea, hmmm, no va a resultar.

Lo que se me ocurre es que **así como buscas un patrón para saber qué es una sección, puedes ocupar el mismo para saber lo que NO es**

```
while not re.findall('\[(.*?)\]',next_line):
  ...
  next_line = next(f)
```

Pero tenemos un segundo problema:

Si tu json está mál formado (y es justo el caso) el parseo artesanal de usar ":" para inferir llave/valor no resulta.

Fíjate que esto:

```
{
  cd /dirname/
  ls
}
```

no es un objeto, no está entrecomillado, no está separado por comas...

Pensemos entonces que es un array (o lista)

```
[
  "cd /dirname/",
  "ls"
]
```

todavía persiste el problema del parseo artesanal, así que yo sugeriría usar la librería JSON nativa. Acá en vez de parsear línea por línea concateno el texto hasta que viene la otra sección, y en ese momento lo parseo (hay que meter un catch ahí en todo caso)

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
import json
ini_dict={}

with open('misterio.ini', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        re_found = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', line)
        re_found = ''.join(re_found)
        ini_dict[re_found] = dict()
        try:
            if re_found:
                next_line = next(f)
                concatenated=''
                while not re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', next_line):
                    concatenated+=next_line    
                    next_line = next(f)
                jsontext = json.loads(concatenated)
                ini_dict[re_found]=jsontext
            else:
                pprint(line)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
    pprint(ini_dict);
```

Con eso vamos casi bien, pero fíjate que para saber si la línea siguiente es una sección tenemos que leerla, luego al salir del bucle, el bucle principal se habrá perdido la sección (en este caso es la sección 'Options').

Considerando que nuestro JSON será un objeto o un array (aunque en realidad no sé) habría que decir que cada json termina con `}` o `]`. Lo malo es que si hacemos esto:

```
 while not re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', next_line) and '}' not in next_line and ']' not in next_line:
```

no entramos al bucle en la última línea del JSON y nuestros objetos quedan mutilados.

Lo único que se me ocurre es que, luego de concatenar, salimos antes:

```
            concatenated=''
            while not re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', next_line):
                concatenated+=next_line    
                if('}' in next_line or ']' in next_line):                            
                    break
                next_line = next(f)
            jsontext = json.loads(concatenated)
            ini_dict[re_found]=jsontext
```

Con este cambio, y modificando tu archivo para ser:

```
 [Settings]
  {
    "Name":"Filename",
    "Version":"1.5",
    "Author": "Authorname",
    "Bolean": true
  }
 [Options]
{
 "Options":"option"
}
 [Script]
  [
   "cd /dirname/",
   "ls"
  ]
```

Me da este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Muchisimas gracias! Sólo tengo un pequeño error se imprime así: {'Script': [u'Command', u'another'], 'Settings': {u'NeedsProxy': False, u'Name': u'Spotify', u'Author': u'MrZ3r0', u'LastModified': u'01-29-2020', u'StartText': u'', u'CustomAgent': False, u'Version': u'1.0', u'CustomInputs': u'', u'RandomAgent': True, u'Description': u'Bassed on spotibrute php'}} ¿A qué se deben la U?

Comment: ¡Ya lo resolví, musichimas gracias, tío!

Comment: Tengo un problema, mira: sí pongo unos [] dentro del json me sale un error.

Comment: Edita la pregunta añadiendo (no reemplazando) el json editado. puede ser que no hayas entrecomillado o separado por coma el "cd dirname ls"

Comment: Ya  edite, supongo que es la expresión regular o algo así. Mira dónde dice "custominputs":[] y "MoreInputs":[{}]

Comment: en tu ejemplo claro, es por el truco que yo hice que no sirve cuando hay arrays anidados. Pero estuve intentando con más cabeza y hay demasiados casos de borde. Creo que me rindo, colega

Comment: De todos modos, me ayudaste de mucho. ¡Gracias!